# Visual Studio 10, JavaScript intellisense inside javascript.js file, and where is the MicrosoftAjax-vsdoc.js

Tags: ajax, intellisense, vsdoc

I can get javascript intellisense going from and aspx or master page ie

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js"type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.isFunction( 
</script>
```

gives me a drop down in vs2010.

I do all(most) of my js coding inside a js file.
How do I get intellisense drop downs inside js files ?

Also, is there a vsdoc for ms ajax (MicrosoftAjax-vsdoc.js) ?

Comment: I completely missed the second part of that...I've never seen such a  vsdoc file, the debug version would be the closest thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the top of your `.js` file add this:

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.4.1.js" />
```

Or make the path relative, if it's not in the same directory, it'll look for the `jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js` when grabbing it for intellisense, any file you reference like this it'll look for the `-vsdoc` version if available.  As a side note, [jQuery 1.4.2 has additional bug fixes](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/02/19/jquery-142-released/) you should consider upgrading :)

Comment: And I also tried yep, well done.  At the top of my js file, I put 
/// <reference path="../MicrosoftAjax/20100604/MicrosoftAjax.debug.js" />
Sys.Net.WebServiceError( 
and then I got intellisense drop downs ...